# rango de fechas SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

mi pregunta es la siguiente

quiero hacer una query donde ponga determinada fecha y me traiga los registros  anteriores y

posteriores(dentro del rango de 7 dias, osea 7 dias anteriores a la fecha puesta y 7 dias posteriores a la fecha puesta)

No pretendo que me lo resuelvan sino que me orienten

primero que nada se puede hacer?

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: si, se puede hacer... qué has intentado?

Comment: se que tengo que usar el between con el datediff puede ser? pero no encuentro la logica de como hacerlo

Comment: Para entender bien...pones una fecha, por ejemplo `'20190215'`, y quieres todos los registros de 7 días anteriores a esa fecha (`'20190208'`) y los 7 días posteriores (`'20190222'`)...incluyendo el `'20190215'`?, excluyéndolo?, 15 días en total?

Comment: exactamente, si se puede incluir tambien '20190215'    alguna idea?

Comment: Qué tipo de dato es la columna sobre la cuál aplicarías el filtro?

Comment: el tipo de dato de la columna es datetime

Comment: Creo que deberías usar dateadd:`select DATEADD(dd, 7, current_timestamp), DATEADD(dd, -7, current_timestamp)`. dd es el rango que quieres usar, puede ser días, meses, años. El número 7 (y el -7) es para indicar cuánto quieres sumar o restar a la fecha que pasar como parámetro. Con current_timestamp estoy pasando la fecha actual, pero tú puedes pasarle cualquier fecha que quieras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es bastante sencillo, pero constantemente veo varias soluciones que implican usar una función sobre la columna de la tabla que se quiere filtrar, impidiendo el uso de un índice en esa columna.

En este caso, lo mejor es usar un filtro sobre la columna directamente, y no usar `BETWEEN` si estás usando `datetime` (ya que puedes filtrar fechas sin darte cuenta, al tener un componente de tiempo):

```
DECLARE @Fecha date;
SET @Fecha = '20190215';

SELECT *
FROM dbo.TuTabla
WHERE colFecha >= DATEADD(DAY,-7,@Fecha)
AND colFecha < DATEADD(DAY,8,@Fecha)
;
```

Comment: Excelente me sirvio Lamak! Muchas gracias